# Trigger cloud firestore

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I need help in Cloud Functions.
I previously deployed micro-services written with Python and so, got URL address to execute the script.
Now, I would like to execute this URL when a document is written in my Cloud Firestore. If I understood, I need Cloud Functions to do it but someone can help me ?

For example, every time I add a document in "temp" collection, I would like to execute my URL.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should call your URL from the Cloud Function, for example with the [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) library.

You will find a lot of examples on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=axios+cloud+function

If you encounter any problem, update your question with all the details.

---

**Important (if you are using Cloud Functions for Firebase):**

You need to be on the "Blaze" pricing plan.

As a matter of fact, the free "Spark" plan "allows outbound network requests **only to Google-owned services**". See https://firebase.google.com/pricing/ (hover your mouse on the question mark situated after the "Cloud Functions" title)